# How can I count how many tries I've taken?

Tags: python, count

So I'm trying to coutn how many tries it takes to guess the mixed up words. Quite frankly, I've been stuck for so long because this code doesn't work at all. Please help.

```
#Word Jumble Game
import random
import string


words = ['Jumble', 'Star', 'Candy', 'Wings', 'Power', 'String', 'Shopping', 'Blonde', 'Steak', 'Speakers', 'Case', 'Stubborn', 'Cat', 'Marker', 'Elevator', 'Taxi', 'Eight', 'Tomato', 'Penguin', 'Custard']

def jumbled():
    word = string.lower(random.choice(words))
    jumble = list(word)
    random.shuffle(jumble)
    scrambled = "".join(jumble)
    print '\n',scrambled,'\n'

    guess = raw_input('Guess the word: ')

    count=0

    if guess == word:
        print '\n','Correct!'
    else:
        print '\n','Try again!','\n',jumbled()
    count+=1

jumbled()
```

Comment: please fix you indentation.  It looks like you might want to use a loop somewhere

Comment: *"doesn't work at all"* is not a problem description. What do you want your code to do? What does it do instead?

Answer (score 0):

There you go. I have fixed few things for you. My fixes will be mentioned in the comments of my code down below. Let me know if this helped you in fixing your code.

```
 #Word Jumble Game
    import random
    import string

    def jumbled():
        words = ['Jumble', 'Star', 'Candy', 'Wings', 'Power', 'String', 'Shopping', 'Blonde', 'Steak', 'Speakers', 'Case', 'Stubborn', 'Cat', 'Marker', 'Elevator', 'Taxi', 'Eight', 'Tomato', 'Penguin', 'Custard']
        count =0                       ## initialize the count value.
        flag = True                    ## I have used flag as to when to stop executing the program (depending on the value of flag) 
        while flag:                    ## Let it run infinitely till user gets right answer!
            word = string.lower(random.choice(words))
            jumble = list(word)
            random.shuffle(jumble)
            scrambled = "".join(jumble)
            print '\n',scrambled,'\n'

            guess = raw_input('Guess the word: ')

            if guess.lower() == word:    ## I have used guess.lower() to match with word.lower(). You had missed out to convert guess to lower case!
                print '\n','Correct!'
                count+=1                          ## increment the counter 
                flag = False
                print "Number of guesses you took to get right answer=",count  ## print the count
            else:
                print '\n','Try again!','\n'
                count+=1                          ## increment count for every wrong answer
                print "You had %d tries" %count   ## let user know how many tries he had. 
    jumbled()
```

Comment: Haha that's great dude, thanks for going out of your way! Legend!

Answer (score -1):

```
#Word Jumble Game
import random
import string


 words = ['Jumble', 'Star', 'Candy', 'Wings', 'Power', 'String', 'Shopping', 'Blonde', 'Steak', 'Speakers', 'Case', 'Stubborn', 'Cat', 'Marker', 'Elevator', 'Taxi', 'Eight', 'Tomato', 'Penguin', 'Custard']


def jumble_word(word_list):
    word  = random.choice(word_list)
    jumble = ''.join(random.shuffle(list(word)))
    return word, jumble

def play(word_list):
    word, jumble = jumble_word(word_list)
    count = 0
    while True:
        print('Guess the word: {}'.format(jumble))
        guess = input('Enter your guess: ')
        guess += 1
        if word == guess:
            print('Correct! You got the word in {} tries!'.format(count))
            break
        else:
            print('Guess again! You have guessed {} times.'.format(count))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    play()
```

This will function the way you want it to.